# Disappearing fonts in an active directory

Tags: fonts, active-directory

I'm managing an active directory but I sometimes get calls because some fonts disappear.

I've given some people the rights to add new fonts into c:/windows/fonts

Does someone got a clue why this is happening?

Maybe it has to do something to do with the space problem on the domain server but fonts are local?

Answer (score 1):

How technical are these users? Do you think they are inadvertently removing fonts as well?
I would monitor user activity to the directory and see what actions are being taken. If it turns up that no one is removing the files then you may something else going on.

Comment: How do you suggest i could do that?? is there a tool ?

Comment: You can use the Windows Performance logs or you can use this tool: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/monitor-log-folder-activity-to-perform-actions-on-events/